# What could be the reason for error message Unexpected Goto in batch file with many string compares?

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code of my batch file:

```
:add_game_now
cls
echo Add a Game!
echo V for Victory and D for Defeat
set /p add_game=

if %add_game%==V goto add_game_now_v
if %add_game%==D goto add_game_now_d

:add_game_now_v
set /a elo=%elo%+20
if %division%==bronze goto add_game_bronze_v
if %division%==silver goto add_game_silver_v
if %division%==gold goto add_game_gold_v
if %division%==platinum goto add_game_platinum_v
if %division%==diamond goto add_game_diamond_v
if %division%==master goto add_game_master_v
if %division%==challanger goto add_game_challanger_v

:add_game_now_d
set /a elo=%elo%-15
if %division%==bronze goto add_game_bronze_d
if %division%==silver goto add_game_silver_d
if %division%==gold goto add_game_gold_d
if %division%==platinum goto add_game_platinum_d
if %division%==diamond goto add_game_diamond_d
if %division%==master goto add_game_master_d
if %division%==challanger goto add_game_challanger_d
```

The problem is that when I am at `:add_game_now` and enter `V` or `D` I get the message `Unexpected Goto` and then it exits.

What could be the reason for this error message?

If you need the entire file I can send it.

Thanks for helping and Yes I am not good at coding.

Comment: are you sure,`%add_game%`  and  `%division%` aren't empty?

Comment: I am sooooo stupid.... %division% was empty because i forgot to update another part of the code.... Thank You SOOOOO Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of enumerating all these GOTO target labels you can use the value of the variable within the label name:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
REM goto :EOF will terminate the batchfile
REM this only works if Extensions to CMD are enabled

:add_game_now
cls
echo Add a Game!
echo V for Victory and D for Defeat
set /p add_game=

GOTO add_game_now_%add_game%
GOTO :EOF

:add_game_now_V
:add_game_now_v
set /a elo=%elo%+20
GOTO add_game_%division%_v 
GOTO :EOF

:add_game_now_D
:add_game_now_d
set /a elo=%elo%-15
GOTO add_game_%division%_d 
GOTO :EOF
```

Make sure that all these labels exist! Otherwise the batch will crash. The variable `division` also has to exist and must have a value (like 'bronze').
Consider to use `CHOICE` instead of `set /p`. This way, you can make sure that only uppercase entries are allowed and only 'V' or 'D'. You will not need the doubled labels anymore then.

Comment: So I have another question.... while i kept working on this file.....  I realized another problem which is.........                                         Code:                             "if %division%==Bronze V" - without ""                                                                                                    It does not read the V on the end of Bronze V in this case. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @xMaisha, the syntax for string compares in an IF condition in a batch file is: `if /I "%division%"=="Bronze V"`. The parameter `/I` results in a case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Yes, you have to put double quotes ( " ) around text which contains spaces. So: `if /i "%division"=="Bronze V"`. Please note that you don't need all these IFs in my suggested answer.